# Trying to install caffe on mac os

Tags: macos, homebrew, boost-python

on running the following step :brew install -build-from-source -fresh -vd boost boost-python

It throws an below error

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/boost.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/boost-python.rb
Error: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.62.0
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/keg.rb:172:in `realpath'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/keg.rb:172:in `realpath'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/keg.rb:172:in `for'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:574:in `linked_version'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:193:in `block in install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:126:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:126:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:91:in `<main>'
```

Please let me know how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error rises because of boost version.
for solving this issue :

```
    Step 1:brew search boost
    check the compactability of your boost version.
    Step 2:brew uninstall boost
    Step 3:brew install boost
```